# Beginner java for-loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

this code:

```
for(int i=5; i<50; i=i*2){ 
}
```

Why does it loop 4 times instead of 3? I thought it did 5x2 which = 10, then 10 x 2 which = 20, then 20 x 2 which = 40, and stops there since 40 x 2 is greater than 50.

Comment: You're missing the first execution. It starts with `5` and checks `5 < 50`. It then proceeds to execute and when done it checks `5*2 < 10`, executes and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Print the numbers:

```
for (int i = 5; i < 50; i = i * 2) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Output:

```
5
10
20
40
```

So you are missing the first iteration when `i == 5`.

Incidentally, `i = i * 2` can be written as `i *= 2`.

Answer (score 2):

The first execution uses the assigned value of `i`. It only iterates after executing. So it will run once before the three times that you have listed.

Answer (score 1):

On the first iteration `i` is **5**.

The second time it loops, `i` is **10**.

The third time `i` is **20**.

After the third iteration `i` is **40**. Has `i` passed **50** yet? No.

After the fourth iteration `i` is **80**, and we exit the loop.

That makes **4** iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the start:

```
if i < 50 --> do a iteration
```

`i=5` --> less than 50 --> first loop;

Now the increment of `i` --> `i = i*2` --> `i = 5*2 = 10`

`i=10` --> less than 50 --> second loop;

Now the increment of `i` --> `i = i*2` --> `i = 10*2 = 20`

`i=20`--> less than 50 --> third loop;

Now the increment of `i` --> `i = i*2` --> `i = 20*2 = 40`

`i=40` --> less than 50 --> fourth loop;

Now the increment of `i` --> `i = i*2` --> `i = 40*2 = 80`

`i=80` --> bigger than 50 --> stop